# OptaPlanner vehicle routing course grained moves

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on a problem almost identical to the coachshuttlegathering example. I have wastebins and vehicles that should collect the wastebins. Each wastebin has a payload and each vehicle has a capacity.

I setup my solution as shown in the coachshuttlegathering example and this basically works but I end up in local optimas because the default moves are not coarse grained enough. Specifically, I need to allow 2 wastebin chains from 2 distinct vehicles to be assigned to a different vehicle in a single move.

I tried to reuse the existing subChainChangeMoveSelector in combination with a cartesianProductMoveSelector like this:

```
<cartesianProductMoveSelector>
    <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
        <entityClass>...Wastebin</entityClass>
        <subChainSelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>previousRouteComponent</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </subChainSelector>
        <valueSelector>
            <variableName>previousRouteComponent</variableName>
        </valueSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>false</selectReversingMoveToo>
    </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
    <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
        <entityClass>...Wastebin</entityClass>
        <subChainSelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>previousRouteComponent</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </subChainSelector>
        <valueSelector>
            <variableName>previousRouteComponent</variableName>
        </valueSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>false</selectReversingMoveToo>
    </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.5</fixedProbabilityWeight>
</cartesianProductMoveSelector>
```

When I run the solver with this configuration, I get the following exception:

```
The entity (Wastebin{id=3}) has a variable (previousRouteComponent) with value (Wastebin{id=3}) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextWastebin) with a value (Wastebin{id=1}) which is not null.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? One odd thing is that the planning entity apparently points to itself. I was thinking maybe the move selects 2 overlapping subChains which causes inconsistencies at some point?

### EDIT

Turning on FULL_ASSERT yields more details:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UndoMove corruption: the beforeMoveScore (0/0/23/-2245/-12) is not the undoScore (0/0/23/-1358/-2) which is the uncorruptedScore (0/0/23/-1358/-2) of the workingSolution.
  1) Enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT (if you haven't already) to fail-faster in case there's a score corruption.
  2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.CompositeMove). The move ([[Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Vehicle{id=2}}, [Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Wastebin{id=1}}]) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo([[Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Vehicle{id=2}}, [Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Wastebin{id=1}}])).
  3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by the score constraints with a different score weight between the beforeMoveScore (0/0/23/-2245/-12) and the undoScore (0/0/23/-1358/-2).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertExpectedUndoMoveScore(AbstractPhaseScope.java:145)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:153)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:121)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:72)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:215)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
```

Unfortunately, the output contains `move` twice, I created [PLANNER-599](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-599) for this issue. I got the correct undo move from the debugger:

```
[Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Vehicle{id=1}}
[Wastebin{id=3}..Wastebin{id=3}] {Wastebin{id=3} -> Vehicle{id=1}}
```

I do not have any custom VariableListeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue in OptaPlanner 6.4.0.Final](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-611). It happens with complex CompositeMoves and it's due to the design of the Move interface. Fixing it is not trivial, see [PLANNER-611](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-611).

**Update: This is fixed for `7.0.0.CR1`.**

Answer (score 0):

"The entity (Wastebin{id=3}) has a variable (previousRouteComponent) with value (Wastebin{id=3})"

That mean Wastebin-3 is pointing to itself? That would violate the chained variables principles. In theory, the cartesian production move shouldn't be able to cause that - but if your input problems is valid, that must be happening anyway...

Turn on environmentMode FULL_ASSERT and see if it fails earlier.

Comment: I added the results of applying FULL_ASSERT to my original question. Is it possible that the duplicate undo move steps somehow corrupt the variables?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with the vehicle routing example included in the OptaPlanner distribution using FULL_ASSERT and a cartesianProductMoveSelector as described in my question. Still no idea what is going on.

Comment: Can you share a PR on optaplanner-examples with a unit test that fails?

Comment: I have created the [PR](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/pull/201)

Comment: Has anyone been able to find a work around for this issue? Or can recommend an approach for finding one?

Comment: For `7.0.0.CR1` the CompositeMove bug has been solved, so the cartesianProdcutMoveSelector has been fixed, so this should be fixed.